# creating date from format php

Tags: php, date, date-conversion

Trying to convert a date with the format `Jul 27, 2015 5:42:05 PM` This is the current way that I'm trying to create the date from the format that I've been provided.

```
$newDate = new DateTime::createFromFormat('m d, y H:i:s', $game->createDate);
```

It doesn't like the way that I'm currently doing it. Do I need to try and rework the way that the date comes to me?

This is how I am printing it currently `echo date_format($newDate, 'Y-m-d');`

Comment: get rid of the `new` keyword. It doesn't get used when calling a static method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createFromFormat` is a static method. You don't `new` it:

```
$new = DateTime::createFromFormat(...);
```

it'll do the `new` business for you internally.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to deal with the AM/PM or does that already deal with it?

Comment: Just found the php api and saw that. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcB How would I go about printing the date?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `new` keyword. In addition, your format string doesn't match the date string you gave.  This should work:

```
$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d, Y h:i:s a', $game->createDate);
```